# Does Play Framework with the Scala plugin support MVC and  the Java API?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

Some questions:

1. Why when I generare a new play app with scala is there no model folder?
2. Can I use JPA instead of Anorm?
3. I saw some similarities between Ruby on Rails and Play. So are there any helper methods in Play Framework (form helper, link helper, etc)?
4. Is it possible to use the Play Java Framework with Scala?

Answer (score 2):

> Why when I generare a new play app with scala is there no model folder?

For simple apps, you just define one `models.scala` file. You don't necessarily need a folder, even when you're using the `models`package. Less visual clutter so to speak. When your app grows bigger you can refactor and put everything in a separate folder.

> Can I use JPA instead of Anorm?

Of course. But you should definitely check out Anorm, or Squeryl, or ...

> I saw some similarities between Ruby on Rails and Play. So are there any helper methods in Play Framework (form helper, link helper, etc)?

There are some special shortcut tags, especially in the Groovy markup (checkout out the cheat sheet). Creating your own partial components is simple enough, however. The concept of helper doesn't really exist AFAIK.

> Is it possible to use the Play Java Framework with Scala?

Haven't tried it for myself but I've read that you can mix Java and Scala classes, the compiler will compile everything you throw at him.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend implementing the tutorial on [play website](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/home#TutorialPlayScalaguidearealworldappstepbystep). Also, you may want to try the [scalagen](http://www.playframework.org/modules/scalagen) module - it would give you an easy way to generate code while you are learning at least. A quick disclaimer - I wrote the module :-)

Comment: there is a big gap in documentarion for play with scala :)                               [link](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/home) very well organized. But seems to me that for plat with scala there is no documentation. [link](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/home)

Comment: yup the documentation is indeed a bit out of date. You can certainly use JPA with scala and also the play java framework. let me know if you need any specific help. like i said before, you can try the scalagen module, it will give you a good start and do some of the basic plumbing.